# servlet mapping how Tomcat does it actually?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have installed Tomcat and browse to their example http://mylocalhost.com:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample

But when I look at servlet mapping in web.xml here it is for HelloWorldExample

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

why is **examples** missing, shouldn't it be instead :

```
<url-pattern>/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url to access a web project is

`http://yourHost:yourPort/yourProjectName`

From this you can make out that `examples` is the name of your project or the `context root` of your project.

so when you give the url like `http://mylocalhost.com:8080/examples`

First the container reads the `deployment descriptor`'s `<welcome-file-list>` tag and displays the file specified under `<welcome-file>` if it is present.

when you specify this url
`http://mylocalhost.com:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample`
the container again searches the `deployment descriptor` for the specified url `/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample` and if it finds one it loads the corresponding class specified.

Answer (score 1):

"examples" is the folder name of the Project. It's name will be included in the apps path.

Comment: it means I have that this part of url must be the same as the PHYSICAL folder of my app ? Is this mandatory : what if I want to have another url for that app name ?

Comment: the /servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample starts from the src folder of the application down to the servlet.

Comment: OK but how do I specify this url with "MyOwnApp" instead of "examples" http://mylocalhost.com:8080/MyOwnApp/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample